# Test a version of a software in a Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, version

I am trying to tell the user if the version of virtualenv he is using is not up-to-date.

But it doesn't work yet. Any idea ?

```
virtualenv:
    if [ ! -f $(PYTHON) ]; then \
        version=`$(VIRTUALENV) --version`;\
        check="1.8.2";\
        winner=`echo -e "$${version}\n$${check}" | sed '/^$$/d' | sort -nr | head -1`;\
        if [[ "$(winner)" = "$(version)" ]]; then \
            $(VIRTUALENV) $(ROOT_DIR)/lib/virtualenv; \
        else \
            echo "Please upgrade your virtualenv>=1.8.2";\
            exit 1;\
        fi \
    fi
```

Comment: Why not simply `case $$($(VIRTUALENV) --version) in 1.8.2) true;; *) false;; esac` You might want to add some diagnostics etc but the comparison code looks much too complex and brittle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok it was a little Makefile trick with $

```
virtualenv:
    if [ ! -f $(PYTHON) ]; then \
        version=`$(VIRTUALENV) --version`;\
        check="1.8.2";\
        winner=`echo -e "$${version}\n$${check}" | sed '/^$$/d' | sort -nr | head -1`;\
        if [[ "$${winner}" = "$${version}" ]]; then \
            $(VIRTUALENV) $(ROOT_DIR)/lib/virtualenv; \
        else \
            echo "Please upgrade your $${version} version of virtualenv to >= 1.8.2";\
            echo "    $ sudo pip install -U distribute pip virtualenv";\
            exit 1;\
        fi \
    fi
```

Comment: You might consider putting this in a .sh file, and calling the .sh file in the target. I use Make for scripting bash a lot, and just to keep from massive amounts of \'s and $$'s, I tend to have a mix of 'inline' single-line bash commands in targets, and bash callouts for the larger scripts that don't use a lot of Make variables. YMMV